# how does work setvbuf() in C

Tags: c

can someone explain me how does `int setvbuf(FILE *stream, char *buffer, int mode, size_t size)` C function works?

I think it sets a buffer for a file stream and stores data in the buffer allocated by `setvbuf` in `size_t` size chunks of data, am I right? And when the buffer is full it is flushed?

sorry I am new here

Comment: The documentation is here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html

Comment: Did you search before asking? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/

Comment: Next time you should show some effort, I answered your first question so you still be motivated to learn and write better questions.

Comment: ++ For [A good code example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/setvbuf).

Comment: [^]
++ Also, 4 places for data flow (I could be wrong):
++ `printf()` moves `regular String` (eg: a `printf("He")` in your code) to **`user-space buffer`**
++ `write()/fflush()` moves **`user-space buffer`** to `kernel buffer cache`
++ `fsync()` moves `kernel buffer cache` to `disk file (/ disk file cache)`
++ 
++ `setvbuf()` sets the **`user-space buffer`** to use & sets mode for: _determining when the `write()` is called (to flush the **`user-space buffer`**), by looking at how (how much / what) the **`user-space buffer`** is filled with, (after you have called many times `printf()`)_.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you did search google, but you need some help understanding what you have found:

I am quoting interchangeably  [gnu documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html) and [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setvbuf):

```
 int setvbuf (FILE *stream, char *buf, int mode, size_t size)
```

> After opening a stream (but before any other operations have been
> performed on it), you can explicitly specify what kind of buffering
> you want it to have using the setvbuf function. The facilities listed
> in this section are declared in the header file stdio.h.

The arguments description:

> stream     -   the file stream to set the buffer to
>
> buffer     -   pointer to a buffer for the stream to use
>
> mode   -   buffering mode to use. It can
> be one of the following values:
>
> _IOFBF    full buffering
>
> _IOLBF    line buffering
>
> _IONBF    no buffering
> size   -   size of the buffer

If you switch for the `c` documentation in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf) you will find the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(void)
{
    int file_size;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    FILE * fp = fopen("test.txt","w+");
    if (setvbuf(fp,buffer,_IOFBF,BUFSIZ) != 0)
    {
       perror("setvbuf()");
       fprintf(stderr,"setvbuf() failed in file %s at line # %d\n", __FILE__,__LINE__-3);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 
    /* Exhibit the contents of buffer. */
    fputs ("aaa",fp);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    fputs ("bbb",fp);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    fputs ("ccc",fp);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    file_size = ftell(fp);
    printf("file_size = %d\n", file_size);
    fflush (fp);              /* flush buffer */
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    fputs ("ddd",fp);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    fputs ("eee",fp);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
 
    rewind(fp);               /* flush buffer and rewind file */
    char buf[20];
    fgets(buf,sizeof buf,fp);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
 
    fclose(fp);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
aaa
aaabbb
aaabbbccc
file_size = 9
aaabbbccc
dddbbbccc
dddeeeccc
aaabbbcccdddeee
```

Pay attention for the following things:

1. What happens when you `fflush` the `FILE *fp`.
2. What `buffer` contains after `fputs` string to `fp`.
3. What happens when you `rewind(fp)`, reread from the file all you have been written.

Don't be afraid of documentation/ manual pages, if you get used to them and read them you will be a great developer, moreover now you are familiar with http://en.cppreference.com/, which is very good source to get start with new API functions, good luck.

Comment: Nice answer. q: Are you aware if there's a similar function that configures buffering for wide chars?

Comment: @Nik-Lz  no please share its name

Comment: That is why I asked. I don't know, from the 10 minute search I did, I haven't found one. If I do I will share the name, please do the same.

Comment: @Nik-Lz please ask it as a new question! I couldn't find one. If you do so, please add a link here.

Comment: I have added a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52903141/is-there-an-equivalent-to-setvbuf-in-c-or-c-to-handle-wide-characters). Feel free to edit if you want to add extra information and context.