# Is there an equivalent to setvbuf() in C or C++ to handle wide characters?

Tags: c++, c, character-encoding, stream, buffer

The C++ [`std::setvbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setvbuf) function enables the regulation of a file stream by various buffering options. That stream can only process plain `char`s though. Is there an equivalent version for wide characters (`wchar_t`) available?

Comment: [`std::basic_filebuf::setbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're using wide or normal chars, the buffer's going to be the same.

Comment: There is no need for an equivalent — you provide an array of `char` big enough to hold whatever number of `wchar_t` characters you want.  You might have to make sure it is sufficiently well aligned, that's all.

Comment: I have to supply a `char*` buffer as argument. If my buffer is `wchar_t*` or `std::wstring` or something similar how could I handle that?

Comment: You probably don't want a stream of `wchar_t`. Remember that [UTF-8 is everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/). Then you need to decode UTF-8 from a `char` stream.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch On Windows Win32 api I want either `wchar_t*` or `std::wstring`.

Comment: Even on Windows, you'll better use UTF-8. Then the file stream has *bytes* and you decode them as UTF-8. How to do that is a different question

Comment: Uses `sizeof(wchar_t)` elements of the buffer per character. Or maybe it converts it to  utf-8 or another multibyte encoding first, depending on what your locale is and your stdio implementation. But there's only one buffer used no matter what you're writing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So you're saying I should provide a char array of double the size of the wcharacters I want?

Comment: It is not a *array of characters* but an array of bytes, which - too - are called `char` in C.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala byte is `unsigned char`.

Comment: C used plain `char` for bytes long before Java turned up on the scene.

Comment: Yes.  If you want a buffer of N `wchar_t` characters, provide a buffer of size `N * sizeof(wchar_t)` bytes — as regular `char` since the `setvbuf()` function expects a `char *` and not an `unsigned char *`.  Note that `wchar_t` does not have to be twice the size of a `char`; it could be 1 or 4 times the size quite plausibly (on different platforms), and the size range could be bigger than that, even.

Comment: On many Unix systems, `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4`.

Comment: `wchar_t`: just say no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setvbuf` works in Windows 8+ to enable writing UTF8 in console window. Reading UTF8 is still not supported as of Windows 10 build 1803.

In Visual Studio you can use compiler specific `_setmode` to read/write UTF16 in console window. But this may not be an option in other compilers (MinGW-32 didn't support it last time I checked). The only other option would be to write your stream functions based on `WriteConsoleW`.

Note that the console window may not support printing Unicode code points above `0xFFFF` unless you change the console font to appropriate font with `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`, such as `"MS Gothic"` (which still doesn't handle many code points)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 

int main() 
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"UTF16 English ελληνικά\n";

    std::wstring utf16;
    std::wcin >> utf16;
    std::wcout << utf16 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```